# Problema com Paginação e forward com Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, zend, paginação, framework

Uso `ZF1` e estou com problemas em usar o `_forward()`, o motivo é que se eu dou um redirect com ele para uma pagina com paginação, a url fica com o método do ação que foi submetido. Bem, por exemplo, se eu tenho uma paginação e cada item tem o botão de excluir com seu `ID` e eu clico para deletar e depois da um forward na pagina a URL que estava `.../index/consultar/pagina/3` fica `../index/apagar?idRegistro=196` e se mudo de página fica `../index/apagar/pagina/5` saindo de fato do padrão, talvez eu não esteja fazendo certo.

Mas segue o paste dos códigos. (Não sou o programador mais profissional ainda, então não repare muito no meu código as vezes ruim. )

http://pastebin.com/RJgABKUW - IndexController

http://pastebin.com/hAvX8sTC - paginacao.phtml

http://pastebin.com/nqnbw6su - consultar.phtml

E eu tenho esse problema com a paginação também pelo fato de que se eu faço uma pesquisa especificando algum dado (filtro) ai ela traz a primeira página com dados e quantidade de paginas equivalente a paginação na pesquisa. Porém se eu vou para pagina 2º ele tipo muda a paginação como se fosse pesquisando todos os dados.

Answer (score 0):

Tente enviar seu formulário de busca via GET ao invés de utilizar POST pois os dados irão permanecer na URL quando o paginationControl utilizar o url helper para construir a url das demais páginas.

Já no caso do forward, utilize o url helper para construir os links dos botão excluir.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'minha-controller', 'action' => 'excluir'), null, false); ?>">Excluir</a>
```

Desta forma, os parâmetros submetidos do formulário irão persistir na URL.